# Reemplazar Null con Dato anterior SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Estoy insertando en una Base de Datos una tabla en Excel y por el volumen de filas lo estoy haciendo a través de un ETL en Visual Studio. Tengo todo listo en mi paquete SSIS y lo traslada sin ningún problema. El inconveniente es que en Excel tengo una columna de Fecha que se refiere a la fecha de generación de ese reporte, es decir para toda la columna es la misma. Pero cuando la **columna Ingreso** es 0 no tiene dato la columna de fecha.

El traslado me lo coloca como NULL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de mi Data Flow posterior al recurso agregue la herramienta de Columna Derivada (Derived Column) agregando la expresión Remplace Null:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo me permite sustituir el Null por el dato que le asigne. ¿Cómo puedo rellenar esos espacios por la fecha del dato anterior que no es NULL? Es decir, que toda la columna no tenga vacíos y que contenga la misma fecha cuando si hay ingreso.

Gracias

Comment: Buen día, me perdí un poco, necesitas que en los campos vacíos de la columna "SNAPSHOT_DATE" se llene con la fecha del día en el cual se están insertando?

Comment: Gracias, exacto los espacios se llenen con la fecha cuando no esta vació! El archivo lo envían de esa manera, es como tomar la fecha cuando no esta vació y rellenar los NULL con dicha fecha. En el ejemplo rellenar con 21/06/22 ¿Cómo puedo obtener ese valor y rellenar?